# MYSQL - Compare NOW() and a date at Paris TimeZone in a request

Tags: mysql, datetime, time, timezone, timestamp

I have a value stored as a DateTime (Paris date-time).
How can I, into a VIEW, know if a stored date is before or equal to NOW(), with NOW() at Paris TimeZone in any case?

PS : I do not have any control over the SQL server.

Comment: Do you know the timezone of the stored date?

Comment: @djacobson:Yes, it's Paris TimeZone. More precisely, it is supposed to be a date-time in Paris.

Answer (score 0):

To Ensure that the date is in paris time zone you can use [`CONVERT_TZ`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) to convert between time zones. For example the following query will compare the `NOW()` date with the stored date and gives you the difference (in days) between them, ensuring that the two dates are in a specific time zone, (I don't know the time zone of paris but this is just an example):

```
select datediff(
                 Convert_TZ(Now(),"SYSTEM","-08:00"),
                 Convert_Tz(AddedIn,"SYSTEM","-08:00")
               ) 
from TableName
```

`System` returns your current time zone, and for `-08:00` is the time zone that you want to convert to as an offset, you can use the name of the time zone or it's offset as specified [MySQL Time zone design pattern](http://www.sjhannah.com/blog/?p=113).

Hope this will help;