# database not returning selected rows

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called profile with a column called last_login which is set to `DATETIME` and when i call this query on my localhost

```
SELECT * FROM profile WHERE `last_login` > DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 20 MINUTE)
```

it works but when i call it on bluehost it doesn't seem to work at all, it returns no rows at all and I've set both of the databases to have the current time and localhost does seem to return what this query is asking but bluehost doesn't seem to return nothing at all.

Comment: What makes you think there's matching data on bluehost?

Comment: Does it work, when you remove the condition? Like this: `SELECT * FROM profile LIMIT 1`? Maybe, you have different timezones on your localhost and on server, and the time is different.

Comment: @DanFarrell setup is the same on both

Comment: @Select the time on server and your localhost, using this query: `SELECT NOW();`

Comment: @user4035 nvm its a hour difference

Comment: Timezones are the likely culprit then, if you're sure the date is correct and should pass on both systems.

Comment: @user4035 How can i change that

Comment: @this.Tony http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8304174/mysql-compare-now-and-a-date-at-paris-timezone-in-a-request

Comment: is there anyway i can change the timezone on bluehost phpmyadmin @user4035

Comment: @this.Tony No, you can't do that. You'll have to adapt your code.

Comment: how would i do that with this piece of code?

Comment: @this.Tony Did you install the dump from your localhost on server? Cause if the user logins on server and the last login time will be updated, using server time, your code will work correctly. And we can just break it, if we hard-code time conversion between timezones.

Comment: i changed all the timezones in php.ini and php files so now it works properly i had a personal question i need to ask you.. @user4035

Comment: @this.Tony Ask it, please.